# Get Data from Choice field in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have searched and tried out all solutions provided for this question in similar problem but they're not working for me. I am getting the following error when trying to get data from an endpoint

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `hotel_type` on serializer `HotelDetailSerializer`. The serializer
>   field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
>   the `Hotels` instance. Original exception text was: 'Hotels' object
>   has no attribute 'get_hotel_Type_display'.

This is my  model field truncated for clarity

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
HOTEL_TYPE = (
        ('hotel', "Hotel"),
        ('apartment', "Apartment"),
        ('villa', "Villa"),
hotel_Type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=HOTEL_TYPE,
        default='hotel', null=True, blank=True
@property
    def hotel_type(self):
        return self.get_hotel_Type_display()
```

This is my serializer class also truncated for clarity

```
class HotelDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    hotel_type = serializers.Field(source='hotel_type.hotel_Type')


    class Meta:
        model = Hotels

        fields = ("hotel_type" )
```

This is the apiview

```
class HotelDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    """Display details of a single hotel"""
    queryset = Hotels.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HotelDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = ()
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Could anyone kindly assist me figure out why this is not working? Thanks

**EDIT**
I am editing this question to add more context. I have been doing some debugging in Django shell. This is what i am getting

```
>>> from hotels.models import Hotels
>>> h = Hotels.objects.all()
>>> for n in h:
...     print (n.hotel_Type)
... 
(<django.db.models.fields.CharField>,)
>>> for n in h:
...     print (n.get_hotel_Type_display())
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Hotels' object has no attribute 'get_hotel_Type_display'
```

I am following Django's `get_FOO_display()` tutorial and i still cannot get this work. I am not seeing anything wrong with my Hotels model. Could this be a bug in Django? Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

This really has eaten me up. I finally found the issue was a misplaced comma on my model field as shown below

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
HOTEL_TYPE = (
        ('hotel', "Hotel"),
        ('apartment', "Apartment"),
        ('villa', "Villa"), 
hotel_Type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=HOTEL_TYPE,
        default='hotel', null=True, blank=True
        ),# <--------------This comma was the source of my problems
@property
    def hotel_type(self):
        return self.get_hotel_Type_display()
```